# My KDE menu bar disappeared

Tags: arch-linux, kde, artix-linux

My KDE menu bar was fine. Then I connected an external display to my laptop, and everything was still fine, with the bar moved to the bigger display. Then, after disconnecting the external display, I cannot reach the menu bar anylonger, at least until I reconnect the external display.

I can drag the menu bar to the laptop display, but when I disconnect the external one, it still disappears (basically it moves to the external display as soon as I disconnect it).

This issue appeared after a recent system update of my Artix Linux (Arch-based).

Does anyone had the same issue? How can I fix it?